# Using WSDL for frontend website login

Tags: xml, database, authentication, wsdl

I'm building a website for a company that wants me to use their internal database of users for frontend website login. They provided me with this:

```
http://80.188.42.243:25250/Cardin_TEST/IntegrationService.asmx?WSDL
```

How do I start using those methods? Or where should I start learning this? This is all totally new. I'd normally do this using PHP and a database of users in mySQL. How do I do this? Thank you

Comment: With WSDL I'd start by using a tool like SoapUI or WebService Studio. That way you can plug in methods and test them outside of the development environment. Then you can eventually port it over to PHP.

Comment: since asmx is IIS and microsoft, webservice studio/app by microsoft may work better.

Comment: is there a simple working example somewhere? I find this all hard to understand, it all seems very vast. I'd like to understand the principle behind it. I have a running website, I have HTML forms and user input. Then what? Just theoretically, if I had all of the necessary connections and stuff like that..

Comment: essentially if i remember correctly you'd pass all parameters through the URL and when it returns it'd format its results in XML. You'd take the XML and parse the data you'd want. PHP has built in classes/libraries for XML parsing, also there exists third party ones. Not sure if there is working examples. You'd just take your HTML form request query data and plug it into the web service URL you mentioned. SoapUI can help you do this.